# bibtex and label/ref

Tags: latex, bibtex

I was wondering how I can add \label into bibtex so that when I cite in my document and I can also \ref to it by clicking it and jumping to the Bibliography at the end?

for example:

```
 @inproceedings{Boser92atraining,  
    abstract = {A training algorithm that maximizes the margin  between the training patterns and the decision  boundary is presented. },  
    author = {Boser, Bernhard E. and Guyon, Isabelle M. and Vapnik, Vladimir N.},  
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 5th Annual ACM Workshop on Computational Learning Theory},  
    citeulike-article-id = {4669426},  
    citeulike-linkout-0 = {http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.21.3818},  
    keywords = {learning, svm},  
    pages = {144--152},  
    posted-at = {2010-04-07 21:30:39},  
    priority = {2},  
    title = {A Training Algorithm for Optimal Margin Classifiers},  
    url = {http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.21.3818},  
    year = {1992}  
}
```

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

in the preamble of your LaTeX document. The generated dvi/pdf file should automatically contain a hyperlink for each

```
\cite{greenwade93}
```

in your document to the bibliography section.

Comment: Yes, I have already include hyperref package. But there is no hyperlink for each \cite. Strange?

Comment: Sorry. I just changed the example to be the real one that I am using, but the problem is still the same.